# How do I enable Asp.Net.Code "Development Mode" on Live website

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

My Asp.Net.Core.3.0 web app runs perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2019, but when deployed to my web-host I get the error displayed in the picture when I try to use one of the functions from my menu. That function works without issue locally.

[image]

I've tried enabling development mode to get a detailed description of the error by doing this in Program.cs

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseEnvironment("Development");
```

Any ideas anyone on how to see what the actual error is?

Comment: Have you checked startup.cs?

Comment: check it for what?